# How to capture one of two things, then the other of two things

Tags: regex

This is a generic regular expression question, that I couldn't find an answer too.

Lets say I have a few input strings:

```
...A-A-B...
...B-A-A...
...A-B-A...
...B-B-A...
```

I have two delimiters `A` and `B`. What I want to do is find either of these, and then look for the other one. Now I know I can do `(A.*B)|(B.*A)` which will match what I want for all four strings.

And I can also do `(A|B).*\1` which would match `A-A` for the first and second strings, `A-B-A` for the third and `B-B` for the last.

**Can I do something alongs the lines of `(A|B).*[^\1]` to say, find one of two tokens then find the other token?**

For context, I was interested in this because of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646862/regex-allows-one-character-it-should-not-why/18647499#18647499), where `A` and `B` are a dot or comma for currency matching, but I figure this could be useful in lots of contexts, hence the generic question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negative lookahead could do it.

```
(A|B).*(?!\1)(A|B)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a conditional:

```
(?:(A)|B).*?(?(1)B|A)
```

`(?(1)B|A)` is an IF..THEN..ELSE and means: *if group 1 then B else A*

Notice: this doesn't work with java, javascript and GO but works with Perl, PHP, Python, Ruby, .net

Comment: Sorry, I upvoted you, but selected the other one as it works everywhere. But the conditional stuff is might cool. Thanks!

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: the only answer that works everywhere is rmmh answer.